# How to create a new column in data.table based on values of other columns

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following data structure in the data.table format:

```
ID  Cycle  Cycle_Day Cycle_Date  Positive_Test_Date
1   1      1         3/28/2019   NA
1   1      2         3/29/2019   NA
1   1      3         3/30/2019   NA
1   1      NA        NA          3/29/2019
1   2      1         4/23/2019   NA 
1   2      2         4/24/2019   NA
1   2      3         4/25/2019   NA
1   2      NA        NA          4/25/2019
2   1      1         3/18/2019   NA
2   1      2         3/19/2019   NA
2   1      3         3/20/2019   NA
2   1      NA        NA          3/18/2019
2   2      1         4/23/2019   NA 
2   2      2         4/24/2019   NA
2   2      3         4/25/2019   NA
2   2      NA        NA          4/24/2019
```

I would like to create a new column "LH_Date" which will, for every ID and every cycle, copy the date in the event Cycle_Date and Positive_Test_Date match. Otherwise the value is NA. This is how it should look:

```
ID  Cycle  Cycle_Day Cycle_Date  Positive_Test_Date LH_Date
1   1      1         3/28/2019   NA                 NA 
1   1      2         3/29/2019   NA                 3/29/2019
1   1      3         3/30/2019   NA                 NA
1   1      NA        NA          3/29/2019          NA
1   2      1         4/23/2019   NA                 NA
1   2      2         4/24/2019   NA                 NA
1   2      3         4/25/2019   NA                 4/25/2019
1   2      NA        NA          4/25/2019          NA
2   1      1         3/18/2019   NA                 3/18/2019
2   1      2         3/19/2019   NA                 NA
2   1      3         3/20/2019   NA                 NA 
2   1      NA        NA          3/18/2019          NA
2   2      1         4/23/2019   NA                 NA
2   2      2         4/24/2019   NA                 4/24/2019
2   2      3         4/25/2019   NA                 NA
2   2      NA        NA          4/24/2019          NA
```

Comment: Is that formatted correctly? Hard to tell...

Comment: Can you kindly add the dput(dt) output of the first, say 20 rows so that we can reproduce your data?

Comment: Sorry, not sure how to do that. Happy to do it if you let me know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to use indexing to find the rows that fits the condition and update those rows only:

```
#for each group of ID and Cycle, 
#find the row indices where Cycle_Date equals the last Positive_Test_Date 
idxDT <- DT[, .I[Cycle_Date==Positive_Test_Date[.N]], .(ID, Cycle)]

#for those row indices, set the LH_Date to be Cycle_Date 
#(NA rows or excluded rows defaults to NA by design in data.table)
DT[idxDT$V1, LH_Date := Cycle_Date]
```

`idxDT` looks like this and `idxDT$V1` extracts the column `V1`:

```
   ID Cycle V1
1:  1     1  2
2:  1     1 NA
3:  1     2  7
4:  1     2 NA
5:  2     1  9
6:  2     1 NA
7:  2     2 14
8:  2     2 NA
```

`.I` contains the row index within a data.table. From `?.I`:

> .I is an integer vector equal to seq_len(nrow(x)). While grouping, it holds for each item in the group, its row location in x. This is useful to subset in j; e.g. DT[, .I[which.max(somecol)], by=grp].

output:

```
    ID Cycle Cycle_Day Cycle_Date Positive_Test_Date   LH_Date
 1:  1     1         1  3/28/2019               <NA>      <NA>
 2:  1     1         2  3/29/2019               <NA> 3/29/2019
 3:  1     1         3  3/30/2019               <NA>      <NA>
 4:  1     1        NA       <NA>          3/29/2019      <NA>
 5:  1     2         1  4/23/2019               <NA>      <NA>
 6:  1     2         2  4/24/2019               <NA>      <NA>
 7:  1     2         3  4/25/2019               <NA> 4/25/2019
 8:  1     2        NA       <NA>          4/25/2019      <NA>
 9:  2     1         1  3/18/2019               <NA> 3/18/2019
10:  2     1         2  3/19/2019               <NA>      <NA>
11:  2     1         3  3/20/2019               <NA>      <NA>
12:  2     1        NA       <NA>          3/18/2019      <NA>
13:  2     2         1  4/23/2019               <NA>      <NA>
14:  2     2         2  4/24/2019               <NA> 4/24/2019
15:  2     2         3  4/25/2019               <NA>      <NA>
16:  2     2        NA       <NA>          4/24/2019      <NA>
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("ID  Cycle  Cycle_Day Cycle_Date  Positive_Test_Date
1   1      1         3/28/2019   NA
1   1      2         3/29/2019   NA
1   1      3         3/30/2019   NA
1   1      NA        NA          3/29/2019
1   2      1         4/23/2019   NA 
1   2      2         4/24/2019   NA
1   2      3         4/25/2019   NA
1   2      NA        NA          4/25/2019
2   1      1         3/18/2019   NA
2   1      2         3/19/2019   NA
2   1      3         3/20/2019   NA
2   1      NA        NA          3/18/2019
2   2      1         4/23/2019   NA 
2   2      2         4/24/2019   NA
2   2      3         4/25/2019   NA
2   2      NA        NA          4/24/2019")
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I am only familiar with the i, j by format of a data.table. If you dont mind I have a couple of questions: 1. what does the double bracket format [[ ]] do in this particular case? In DT[DT[,  ]] if the part before the comma refers to i and you are filtering on rows that fit a condition, why is it empty? 3. what does .I represent? and 4. what is $V1? If my questions are confusing, please feel free to offer your own explanation and I will figure it out. Thanks again!

Comment: hi @user12239114, i have added explanation. hope that its clear now.

Comment: Hi chinsoon12. Yes, that makes sense - thank you so much for your explanation. I get it!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data is in a `data.table` named `DT`:

First filter `DT` where the `Positive_Test_Date` is not `NA` (since they're not useful for creating the new column)

```
ptd_notna <- DT[!is.na(Positive_Test_Date)]
```

Then join your original table with this one on `ID` and `Cycle` and create a new column `idx` which is a boolean indicating whether the `Cycle_Date` of the *table X* is equal to the `Positive_Test_Date` of the *table i* for each group. Think of the join as `X[Y]`, so you refer to the columns of *X* through `x.colname` and the columns of *Y* through `i.colname` (since *Y* is in the `i` part of *X*).

```r
DT[ptd_notna, 
   idx := x.Cycle_Date == i.Positive_Test_Date, 
   on = .(ID, Cycle)]
```

Now you can use this new column `idx` to filter your table and assign the new column `LH_Date` equal to the `Cycle_Date`. Note how to use a boolean column in `i` you use paretheses.

```r
DT[(idx), LH_Date := Cycle_Date]
```

Then remove the `idx` if you don't think you'll need it.

```r
DT[, idx := NULL]
```

Comment: If you have a minute to explain your logic (or point me to the section in data.table documentation) I'd appreciate the teaching moment.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is very helpful. I've gone through this step by step and your explanation for every step makes sense.